# ASP.NET MVC - 'object' does not contain a definition for 'ID'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I got error: object doesn't contain a defination for 'StyleCode'. Infact I get list of record in model when check it on breakpoint what am I missing?

HomeController.cs

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (var context = new ApronPointEntities())
    {
        var styles = (from s in context.STYLEs
            join
            c in context.STYLEPRICEs on s.STYLEID equals c.STYLEID
            select new {
                STYLEID=s.STYLEID,
                STYLECODE=s.STYLECODE,
                STYLENAME= s.STYLENAME,
                PRICE= c.REGULARPRICE
            }).Take(10).OrderByDescending(s =>s.STYLEID).ToList();

        return View(styles);
    }
}
```

--------------Index.cshtml--------------

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{ 
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
        <div class="product">
            <div class="product-cover">
                <span class="product-action">
                    <span class="product-new">New</span>
                    <span class="product-sale">Sale</span>
                </span>
                <div class="product-cover-hover"><span><a href="product.html">View</a></span></div>
                <img src="~/Images/Styles/Img-0.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="product-details">
                <h1><a href="product.html">@item.STYLECODE</a></h1>
                <p>@item.STYLENAME</p>
                <div class="product-price">
                    <i class="icon-257" title="add to cart"></i>
                    @item.PRICE
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: you're returning a collection of anonymous objects, creating a class that represents this would be great!

Comment: @StuartLC its a list

Model ={System.Collections.Generic.List<<>f__AnonymousType1<int,string,string,double?>>}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to recommend you to make an Class i.e. `ViewModel`

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public int STYLEID { get; set; }
    public string STYLECODE { get; set; }
    public string STYLENAME { get; set; }
    public double PRICE { get; set; }
}
```

and give a `List<ViewModel>` to the `.cshtml` file

Answer (score 0):

`@foreach(var item in Model)` What is a type that 'var' resolves to here?

It's most likely an object. You should Cast this to your type before you can access some of its members.